# React Component State not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to implement a hover effect on a div-element like in this codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/XopkqJ5oV

The component in which I want to do this, is a reusable component that is used multiple times on the same page. I suppose that is the reason why I can't get it to work. What am I missing?

Even using the above code won't work in my application.

---

**EDIT**: Thank you for your responses. I found the issue:

I was not letting **ShouldComponentUpdate** know, it should take state.isHovering into account.

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return (
      nextProps.post.id !== this.props.post.id ||
      nextProps.screenshotClickUrl !== this.props.screenshotClickUrl ||
      nextProps.onImageClick !== this.props.onImageClick ||
      nextProps.handleMouseHover !== this.props.handleMouseHover ||
      nextState.isHovering !== this.state.isHovering
    )
  }
```

Comment: is that your code in codesandbox? If so its already working. If not where is your code. Have you tried console.log's in the event binding function and see if events are firing? I updated the render method to reuse the same component and it works which probably mimics what you are asking for. `render(<div><HoverExample /><br/><HoverExample /></div>, document.getElementById('root'));`

Comment: an updated sandbox for you - https://codesandbox.io/s/qq47zm53vq

Comment: @Rikin https://pastebin.com/Tb54MV9f There you go. This is my code!

Comment: Can you make working example in stackblitz that replicates your problem. Have you tried console.log in `handleMouseHover` and see if it is firing once you hover on desired element?

Comment: As @ZoltanToth have in his code link, just use it the same way instead of writing hover logic in `ImagePost` component. Let ImagePost handle Post things while HoverComponent handle hover stuff. Separation of concern.

Comment: Questions need to stand on their own; we should not have to access external sites to understand and/or answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `this` in:

```
  toggleHoverState(state) {
    return {
      isHovering: !state.isHovering // Need a "this" to access state.
    };
  }
```

If you stack the elements too closely it will interfere with the mouse enter/leave events, e.g., if you space them apart:

```
const Foo = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <HoverExample />
      <div style={{height: '2em', border: '1px solid blue'}} />
      <HoverExample />
    </div>
  )
}
```

it work like (I think) you'd expect.

https://codesandbox.io/s/93l25m453o

I put borders around it to help visualize the issue.

If that doesn't make sense, see what happens when you have the hover indicator in an adjacent span rather than stacked:

https://codesandbox.io/s/5k5jj3rpok

Comment: @mowtheone `shouldComponentUpdate` isn't relevant based on your original code, though. If it *was* relevant then the code sample should have reflected on the actual issue better.